# Rotate device Interrupt methods?

Tags: android, methods

The rotation of the phone breaks/interrupt methods? Let say...

```
public void doingSomething() {
  a = 23;
  soundPool.play(soundId1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
  ...
  ... // here occurs the rotation
  ...
  b = 0;
  cuenta.setText("0");
  c = 100;
}
```

In the code above, the method finishes or the rotation breaks the method?

Answer (score 0):

Yes the method execution will break. If you need more info check handling configuration changes documentation on android

Here is a link for reference https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes